# In project Structure why It is showing excluded folder --> venv

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm new to the Python. If I create new project in PyCharm, in the project structure it shows this:

```
venv library root
  - Include
  - Lib
  - Scripts
```

Why it displays like that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new project in recent versions of PyCharm, it will default to automatically create a new [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) for your project.

It is not required, but I'd highly recommend it as it will provide your project with its own isolated Python sandbox so to speak, where you can install additional packages, without interfering with package requirements of other projects you have, or the global Python installation on your system.

By default, this virtual environment will be created in your project folder, in a subfolder called `venv`, this is what you are seeing.